# Designing a Minecraft Redstone Sorter where 64 items in a stack go through hoppers each tick

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

**Problem** 
Currently, I am playing on a server where hoppers transport items at the rate of one stack at a time, and this has proved very difficult to build a sorter for. I'm not at all proficient in redstone building, but have tried building basic sorters and ones that I have found on YouTube and I haven't gotten anything to work.
**Solution** Hopefully one of you is really good at redstone, and can help me design a sorter that can work under these conditions. (I need the sorter that can sort items while I AFK mine at a Cobble Gen for hours on end)

P.S. most of the problem is with the sorter itself because no items will stay in the sorter hopper (bc the whole stack goes into the chest so the hopper doesn't have anything to go off of to sort) so any solution to that would be helpful as well.

Comment: If you could post detailed screenshots of what you tried so far that would also be great!

Comment: What is the input to your sorting system?  very few farms can generate 64 items / tic.  If you are okay with limiting the input rate, then you can just use standard sorting techniques....

Comment: Does this give you an idea how it could work? https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/350567/171580 Honestly I forgot most of that answer there myself by now, but maybe it's a starting point. Also, are you really sure that it's 64 items per game tick, so 1280 items per second? That is an insane speed and basically makes most features of hoppers completely unusable. I think the only way of actually handling this amount of items would be by not using hoppers at all for most of the build. And that would make it much more complicated than in Vanilla. Interesting challenge, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

The only reliable way to deal with such huge throughput of items with a sorter, is parallellizing.

Transport the items using water streams. [Align them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEPfexclNwU) to the edge of the line of hoppers using sea pickles or chests. These hoppers would be the "middle" hoppers from the standard [overflow-proof sorter design by ImpulseSV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IDmxkObgA2s) (you use water stream instead of the top line of hoppers). Obviously after short initial period when filling up, every sorter will only be able to take just one item per 8 game ticks (4 redstone ticks), so if you have 64 items per game tick, your sorter will need to be 256 blocks long - per one item type! - you just need to configure as many sorters (in parallel) to take the same type of the item that there are enough to capture and process the entire input.

Obviously transporting this out through any conventional means like hoppers or dropper lines or even minecarts would be completely impractical, so the bottom hoppers should be emptying into [1-tileable auto-droppers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPQbq9bkD6o) ejecting sorted items into a water stream, one stream per item type. You can similarly align the sorted items and use rows of hoppers to put them into storage.

ps. verify if it's really 64 items per tick sustained, because that's a pretty insane rate and while the above solution will work with it, it's really not practical - nothing is practical with this sort of rates. If it's just short bursts of large amounts of items, it might be smarter to limit the throughput and even it out a bit - snarf the items into a buffer then gradually eject through some auto-droppers.

Answer (score -2):

If hoppers push entire stacks at one time, a sorter is literally impossible, for the same reasons that unstackable items break normal sorters.  you can certainly auto collect cobblestone from your generator, since there's nothing to sort.

Comment: Posting a "this is impossible" answer when there is already an answer above that explains how to do it is counterproductive.

Comment: if you have large groups that will parallelize liek that they are ALREADY SORTED.

Comment: OP wishes to pace an entire mixed inventory of items into a sorter.  You know. mine until your inventory is full, go back home, shove everything into the sorter but the pick.

On OP's server every hopper push empties a slot in a hopper, making it useless as a filter.  Every hopper pull empties a slot in what it pulled from, making IT useless as a filter.  You can't make a sorter without a filter. Dispensers/droppers randomize the slot they remove an item from.

Comment: and even if you somehow managed to use a dropper as a filter, that requires holding back 534 items in the dropper, plus enough in the hopper above to make sure that it also never empties a slot.  and until you get that much of every item you put into it, the sorter simply won't work. And that's assuming the hopper doesn't just wait until there's enough room to put in the whole stack, and that the dropper doesn't dispense stacks as well.