# How can I sort items on a server that has increased hopper speed?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm playing Minecraft on a server that has tweaked the Hopper speed to be faster. No matter what size is, the stack still goes through. The reason for this speed tweak is a plugin the server has for faster item transport.

I'm trying to find a way to filter items by stack (or sometimes lower), however none of the item filters can handle the hopper speed, and I'm not a Redstone genius. What can I do in this case?

Comment: I'm afraid classic sorters are dead to you, but I think a [reserved-spot system](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npjJPlH6BZQ) should still be capable of working as long as you inject items one at a time into the pipeline, e.g. using an auto-dropper.

Comment: Wow, surprisingly this super-specific question was already asked and answered. I'll assume that you're playing Java edition.

Comment: Duplicate of [Item sorter with multiple items per tick](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/350567/item-sorter-with-multiple-items-per-tick)

Comment: @FabianRöling: No. A hopper that draws/dumps 8 items per tick will work just fine with a correctly configured standard overflow-proof  sorter (4 filter, 41 matching), as it will not dump the whole matching stash before getting relocked. At "full stack per tick" it will drain the match and 3 filter items before it gets locked.