How to make an item filter on a server where hoppers draw a stack of items at a time?
I'm playing on a server where the hoppers draw out a stack of items at a time. The issue with this is that in a traditional sorter you need the locking amount of the resource inside the hopper but since it draws the entire stack the second the hopper gets unlocked it will just draw out all of the item meaning you are not filtering anything anymore.
Video examples of how drawing items out works and how a traditional filter works:

https://streamable.com/p40ev5
https://streamable.com/rpq4ot
https://streamable.com/urtj7u


Welcome! Is this behavior due to a mod (since you tagged it)? Because in that case the question will be off-topic for our site's rules

No, mods are on-topic, just not tech support for them.

Related question: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/350567/171580
That system would not work for you, but maybe it can give you inspiration to find a solution yourself. If you do, please post a self-answer!

@FabianRöling yep, and "other abnormal behavior caused by modding", which seems to be the case

Hmm, that is badly worded then, because all modding is abnormal by definition. The point of that rule was to exclude these "I installed a thousand mods and now my game is not starting/showing a black screen/lagging/…" questions. The hopper behaviour in this post seems to be completely intended, just challenging for redstone design. BTW, @ethanjohnc, it might be helpful to link a page of that mod, so that people can try it themselves or read more about it, in case that helps. But I think your videos already showed it quite well.

@FabianRöling I do not quite know what mod the server uses as I believe it was custom made by the developers.
